# How to hide input param in FastApi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

How to hide the request param in OpenApi? I would like to hide user_agent from OpenApi UI.

I have a simple app:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI, Header

app = FastAPI()
   
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(
       user_agent: Optional[str] = Header(None), 
       size: Optional[int] = Body(None)):
    return {"User-Agent": user_agent}
```

Comment: This should give you the wanted results: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1378#issuecomment-764966955

Answer (score 6):

FastAPI in [version 0.73.0](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.73.0) ([related PR](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/3144)) supports this functionality natively: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#exclude-from-openapi.

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import Body, FastAPI, Header

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(
    user_agent: Optional[str] = Header(None, include_in_schema=False), 
    size: Optional[int] = Body(None)
):
    return {"User-Agent": user_agent}
```

[image: User-Agent header is excluded]

Comment: This feature is great, but sadly it doesn't work for `Body` fields. Just putting that here as an FYI for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#modify-the-openapi-schema) OpenAPI schema for hiding arbitrary parameters. The example below hides`paramB`:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def get_items(paramA: int, paramB: int):
    pass


def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="Custom title",
        version="2.5.0",
        description="This is a very custom OpenAPI schema",
        routes=app.routes,
    )
    # Remove paramB
    params = openapi_schema["paths"]["/"]["get"]["parameters"]
    params = [param for param in params if param["name"] != "paramB"]
    openapi_schema["paths"]["/"]["get"]["parameters"] = params
    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema


app.openapi = custom_openapi
```